# Can't figure out how to clear NaNs in Random Forest

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, nan

Getting a ValueError: Input contains NaN when I run the below code

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 1000, random_state = 42)
rf.fit(train_features, train_labels);
```

I have ran the following and got results saying there were no NaNs or infinite values, but a different loop shows them under the train_features array

```
np.any(np.isnan(train_features))
```

I've ran below but it hasn't changed the error I'm receiving

```
train_features = np.nan_to_num(train_features)
train_labels = np.nan_to_num(train_labels)
```

Please help!

edit: adding the full relevant code:

```
features = pd.read_csv(x)
labels = np.array(features['Actuals'])
features = features.drop('Actuals', axis = 1)
feature_list = list(features.columns)
features = np.array(features)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 1000, random_state = 42)
rf.fit(train_features, train_labels);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see in your code, you're only checking for `nan`, not `inf`. Probably there's a better way using `numpy`, but the `pandas` approach should work:

```
with pd.option_context('mode.use_inf_as_na', True):
    pd.DataFrame(train_features).isnull().sum() #Will show you which columns have nan or inf values
    pd.DataFrame(train_labels).isnull().sum()
```

With this you can be sure if there's `nan` or `inf` values. Then you could `fillna`.

Comment: I separately tested for `inf ` using `np.all(np.isfinite(train_features))` I just didn't put it in, my bad.

Unfortunately I can't use the pandas function since they are all made into arrays for the purposes of the random forest.

Comment: But you can turn an array into a dataframe using `pd.DataFrame()` as stated in the answer. What else are we missing from your code? maybe some posterior transformation? Are you turning values into logs?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see that. I put in the code you provided but I'm still having the nan error when I run the training. I've updated the post with my full relevant code.

Comment: if you add `print(features.isnull().sum().sum())` on your second line in your relevant code, do you get a zero? If you do it using the `with` statement in my answer, is it still zero ?

Comment: I got 11 running before changing to an array, running after gets `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'isnull'`

Comment: Ok, so there are null values. Now if you `print(features.isnull()` you'll know which columns have `nan` values. Then, you can do, for example if column "col1" has nan values, `features['col1'] =  features['col1'].fillna(features['col1'].median())`

Comment: i'm glad I could help you !